# Task manager logs for seeing CPU percentages

Tags: powershell, logging, powerbi, cpu, taskmanager

I was given a task from work to analyze the activity of certain applications through CPU percentages according to the task manager.
I know the option to see the history of the activity.
But can anyone tell me how I can see history with more filters?
Anyone know what log they are written for?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at this link https://www.travisgan.com/2013/03/powershell-and-performance-monitor.html?m=1. It uses `Get-Counter` to get cpu info

Comment: SO has rules we are to follow: [Provide MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) --- [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) --- [Don't ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) --- [Proper Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) --- [Why not upload images of code/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) --- [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)